# Convert string array to multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, typescript, multidimensional-array

I have a javascript string array which I want to convert to a multidimensional array:

```
const maps = [
    "local://aaa/bbb/ccc",
    "local://aaa/bbb/ddd",
    "local://aaa/bbb/eee",
    "as://fff/ggg/hhh",
];
```

I want to convert it to this:

```
const maps = [
    {label: "aaa", children: [
            {label: "bbb", children: [
                    {label: "ccc", children: []},
                    {label: "ddd", children: []},
                    {label: "eee", children: []}
                ]}
        ]},
    {label: "fff", children: [
            {label: "ggg", children: [
                    {label: "hhh", children: []}
                ]}
        ]}
];
```

I've tried to do it like this, but it turns out that its not working correctly and I think this is also not the appropiate way to handle this:

```
interface DialogItem {
  label: string,
  children: DialogItem[]
};


const dialogs: string[] = [
  "local://aaa/bbb/ccc",
  "local://aaa/bbb/ddd",
  "local://aaa/bbb/eee",
  "as://fff/ggg/hhh",
];

const mapFolder = (dialogs: string[]) => {

    const maps: DialogItem[] = [];

    for (const dialog of dialogs) {
      const dialogStr: string = dialog.replace(/(\w+):\/\//gi, "");
      const dialogArr: string[] = dialogStr.split("/");

      const parent = maps.find(mapped => mapped.label === dialogArr[0]);
      if (parent === undefined) {
        maps.push({label: dialogArr[0], children: []});
      } else {
        dialogArr.shift();

        const child = parent.children.find(mapped => mapped.label === dialogArr[0]);
        if (child === undefined) {
          parent.children.push({label: dialogArr[0], children: []});
        } else {
          child.children.push({label: dialogArr[1], children: []});
        }
      }
    }
};

mapFolder(dialogs);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could split the string to get an array of paths. Use a `mapper` object to keep track of each nested object and it's path. `reduce` the chunks and return the nested object in each iteration

```js
const maps = [
     "local://aaa/bbb/ccc",
     "local://aaa/bbb/ddd",
     "local://aaa/bbb/eee",
     "as://fff/ggg/hhh"
    ],
    mapper = {},
    tree = { children: [] } // root object

for (const str of maps) {
  let chunks = str.split('//')[1].split("/"),
      path = '';

  chunks.reduce((parent, label) => {
    if (path)
      path += `.${label}`
    else
      path = label

    if (!mapper[path]) {
      const o = { label, children: [] };
      mapper[path] = o;
      parent.children.push(o)
    }

    return mapper[path];
  }, tree)
}

console.log(tree.children)
```

Answer (score 0):

The expected output can be obtained by using nested maps and recursively appending the data to the sub-array. Also, have handled couple of more test cases.

```js
var dialogs = [
  "local://aaa/bbb/ccc",
  "local://aaa/bbb/ddd",
  "local://aaa/bbb/eee",
  "local://aaa/iii/jjj",
  "",
  "as://",
  "as://fff/ggg/hhh",
];

var maps = [];


dialogs.map((dialog) => {
  const dialogStr = dialog.substr(dialog.indexOf("//") + 2, dialog.length);
  const dialogArr = dialogStr.split("/");
  var localObj = maps;
  dialogArr.map((elem) => {
    if (elem.trim() != "") {
      var data = localObj.find(ele => ele.label == elem);
      if (data) {
        localObj = data['children'];
      } else {
        localObj.push({
          label: elem,
          children: []
        });
        localObj = localObj.find(ele => ele.label == elem)['children'];
      }
    }
  });
});

console.log(maps);
```